# How to catch an elusive loader error in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, try-catch

I'm trying to get some data from a php script using a loader and VARIABLES data format. Here's the code I have:

```
myUrlResults = new URLRequest("http://[...]/getData.php");
myUrlResults.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

myResultsLoader = new URLLoader();
myResultsLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
myResultsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendEventCompleteHandler);
myResultsLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, sendEventErrorHandler);
myResultsLoader.load(myUrlResults);
```

And

```
function sendEventCompleteHandler(e:Event) {

    trace('Ok.');
}

function sendEventErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent) {

    trace('Error occured:' + e);
}
```

As you know, Flash gives you a nasty error if the php file is not formatted properly.
But my .php file returns something like this `var1=5&var2=10` and everything works great. However, sometimes, the server has issues and returns `"Too many connections."` which is something Flash doesn't like, because it's not a variable - value pair and I get an error like this:

```
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables$iinit()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/flash.net:URLLoader::onComplete()
```

How to catch this error??

Comment: try set `myResultsLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT` and in your complete handler get the variables yourself after verify the result. You can use a `URLVariable.decode()` and try/catch it there.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! You should have submitted as an answer so I could select it as solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set

```
myResultsLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
```

and in your complete handler get the variables yourself after verify the result.

You can use a URLVariable.decode() and try/catch it there.